# Running a Gradle Install without running the compileTestJava task?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation

Is it possible to do e.g.:

```
gradle clean install regen
```

but ensure that all `compileTestJava` tasks are not ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `gradle clean install regen -x compileTestJava`